# database query in codeigniter where_in is array

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have some id stored in database table with column name "defaultdest" like "1,2,3,4,5,6".
i have fetched it in controller and now i need to make query in my another table that is named "destinations". where i need to fetch the destinations according to Ids is "1,2,3,4,5,6".

here is the query result from another table

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->data;
        $idlists = explode(",", get_option('defaultdest'));
        $data['destlist'] = $this->ui_model->destfetch($idlists);
        $this->load->view('themes/ui/home/'.get_option('uihometype').'', $data);
    }
```

this is my database query in model

```
function destfetch($idlists)
         {
            $this->db->set_dbprefix('');
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where_in('id', $idlists);
            $this->db->from("destinations");
            $query = $this->db->get();

            //print_r($this->db->last_query());
            return $result = $query->result_array();
            
         }
```

Note: idlists values are (returned by get_option method)

```
$idlists = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
```

This is not working, getting blank results.

Comment: Have you checked printing you query that you have commented in your code `print_r($this->db->last_query());`, what are you getting in query can you show us and add in question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where_in works with array not a string. So your $idlists shouldn't be a string with '1,2,3,4,5' but an array of ids.

You can do this by just doing:

```
$idlists = "1,2,3,4,5,6";            //String
$this->db->where_in('id', explode(',', $idlists));
```

**Note:-** `explode()` use for breaks a string into an array.